# Keeping the Footer at the Bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page but out of sight until you scroll to the bottom of the page. I tried using a 'position: fixed' in my CSS but it floats above my content, for absolute it stuck to the middle of the page and covered content. Also, for pages without much content when I don't specify the position or I use 'position: absolute', there is whitespace below the footer. Please provide suggestions.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

header {
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

/* when I use the fixed position, the footer is fixed above my content. What I want is for the footer to remain at the bottom of the page but out of sight. */
<html>
 <body>
  <header>Heading</header>
  <main>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci eos deserunt fugiat doloremque     your text`ut.</p>
  </main>
  <footer>&copy; Copyright, Business</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, something I don't totally understand. You want footer to be always visible on screen or not? If not, footer at end of page, when scroll, at a point you see the footer. But if on top of page footer out of view, right?

Comment: If you want it to stay at the bottom of the page, isn't that what it already does by default, if it's the last item on the page. Maybe you should reword your question

Comment: Yes, that's correct @pierfarrugia

Comment: @Joshua as I said in my question, for pages with less content the footer does not stay at the bottom. There is space below it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a parent div to it, and the parent div has the same width and height as it。
html:

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.footer-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-container">
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand well

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>Heading</header>
<main>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci eos deserunt fugiat doloremque your text`ut.</p>
</main>
<footer>&copy; Copyright, Business</footer>
```

no need to have fixed for footer. Normal flow put footer at the end of document.

min height on main put footer outside of view when on top of page

Answer (score 1):

I am using

---

```
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body main{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Removed below code from the footer section.

```
position: fixed
```

Now main section is taking the available space that viewport. Also if main section content are too long it will be overflow if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can make to footer to stay at the bottom of the page but putting your footer and the content in a same div. Then set the position of the div as relative and make the footer position:absolute. As already footer has bottom:0 attribute, it will stick at the bottom and to view the footer you have to scroll down.

```html
  
  <html>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
           }
          
          header {
            background-color: gray;
          }
          
          footer {
            background-color: gray;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 20px;
            
            width: 100%;
          }
          .container{
            height: 1000px;
            position: relative;
          }
          
    </style>
   <body>
    <header>Heading</header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci eos deserunt fugiat doloremque     your text`ut.</p>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci eos deserunt fugiat doloremque     your text`ut.</p>

        </div>



        <div>
            <footer>&copy; Copyright, Business</footer>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </main>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `display: table-footer-group` in a `display:table` container (`body`).

By setting `min-height: 100vh` to the body, your footer will always stay on bottom without hiding last elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
}

footer {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-footer-group;
}

#big-content {
  height: 2000px;
  align-items: end;
  display: none;
}

input:checked+#big-content {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>Heading</header>
<main>
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci eos deserunt fugiat doloremque your text`ut.</p>
  <label for="more-content">More content</label>
  <input id="more-content" type="checkbox">
  <div id="big-content">end of big content</div>
</main>
<footer>&copy; Copyright, Business</footer>
```